# How to stop vscode integrated terminal from showing output in between multiple lines of input

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, terminal

I'm a beginner with CP, and one day when I was doing CF Round 900 (Div.3) Question C, I found that the integrated terminal in VS Code is showing output in between multiple lines of input. What I did is just copy the entire input into the integrated terminal

My input:

```
12
5 3 10
5 3 3
10 10 55
6 5 20
2 1 26
187856 87856 2609202300
200000 190000 19000000000
28 5 2004
2 2 2006
9 6 40
47202 32455 613407217
185977 145541 15770805980
```

What it looks like in the VS Code integrated terminal after I entered my input:

```
12
5 3 10
5 3 3
10 10 55
6 5 20
2 1 26
187856 8785YES
NO
YES
YES
NO
6 2609202300
200000 190000 19000000000
28 5 2004
2NO
YES
NO
 2 2006
9 6 40
47202 32455 613407217
185977 145541NO
NO
YES
 15770805980
YES
```

My code:

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class C {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int T = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
        for (int t = 0; t < T; t ++) {
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(in.readLine());
            float n = Float.parseFloat(st.nextToken());
            float k = Float.parseFloat(st.nextToken());
            float x = Float.parseFloat(st.nextToken());
            if ((x<(k/2*(1+k)))||(x>k/2*(2*n-k+1))) {System.out.println("NO");}
            else {System.out.println("YES");}
        }
    }
}
```

VS Code is running on a Mac machine.
Could anyone help me? Thanks!

1. I tried to run it in external terminal it works fine, but I still wish to run it in internal terminal.
2. I tried to run a python file but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Just put your input into a file, and use `... < file.txt` to feed it in.

Comment: You can modify the code to implement your requirements. This is not a vscode problem.

Comment: May I know what's going on with the problem? If it has been solved, can you change the status of the answer to help more people with similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

You are reading input and printing output in the same loop. I suggest that you separate input and output into two loops. First get all the input and save it in some kind of data structure like an array and then process the array and print the output.

In the below code I create a class whose members store the values for `n`, `k` and `x`. I create an array and store the class instances that are initialized from the input. Then I process the array.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class C {
    private float  k;
    private float  n;
    private float  x;

    public C(float n, float k, float x) {
        this.n = n;
        this.k = k;
        this.x = x;
    }

    public String test() {
        return (x<(k/2*(1+k)))||(x>k/2*(2*n-k+1)) ? "NO" : "YES";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t = Integer.parseInt(stdin.nextLine());
        C[] cases = new C[t];
        for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
            String line = stdin.nextLine();
            String[] parts = line.split(" ");
            cases[i] = new C(Float.parseFloat(parts[0]),
                             Float.parseFloat(parts[1]),
                             Float.parseFloat(parts[2]));
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
            System.out.println(cases[i].test());
        }
    }
}
```

For anyone interested, the problem is on this webpage:
https://codeforces.com/contest/1878/problem/C